# System.NullRefrenceException while trying to set Session in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session

I am working on a MVC application where i have to store a unique id for the user who visits for a certain amount of time, so i am using Session in my MVC application but whenevr i try to set a value in my Session, i get a null exception. dont know the reason why, i tried

```
 HttpContext.Session["demo"] = "name";

 Session["demo1"] = "username";
```

I tried both the above method but i am not able to set the Session in MVC application.

Comment: above code is inside any `Action` or simple class file.

Comment: Where you are trying to set the session value? In controller?

Comment: There can be several reasons for this behavior: Maybe you did not load any session state module so you cannot use sessions at all or you are trying to access the session state before the module initialized it, i.e. too early in the ASP.net pipeline or you lost affinity to the HTTP context, e.g. by switching to another thread by accident. This may also depend on which version of ASP.net you are using and how your server is configured.

Comment: could you please post more context of that code?

Answer (score 0):

I was calling this method on the constructor, thats the reason i was not able to get the Session, once i moved the code to the Action, everything was working fine.
thank you all